# Pivot table migration not using custom table name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to make a pivot table in Laravel but I'm using spanish terms for the names:

**products** - productos | **distributors** - distribuidores

here is part of the migrations for each:

**distributors migration:**

```
Schema::create('distribuidores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("nombre");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**products migration:**

```
Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("nombre");
            $table->decimal("precio",10,2);
            $table->foreignId("categoria_id")->constrained()->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**pivot table *distribuidor_producto_table* migration**

```
Schema::create('distribuidor_producto', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId("distribuidor_id")->constrained()->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->foreignId("producto_id")->constrained()->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I also added the proper table name in **Distribuidor** model:

```
protected $table = 'distribuidores';
```

But I get the following error with the pivot table migration:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `tienda`.`distribuidor_producto` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constrainhowt is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `distribuidor_producto` add constraint `distribuidor_producto_distribuidor_id_foreign` foreign key (`distribuidor_id`) references `distribuidors` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

As you can see after *references* it mentions *distribuidors* which I understand is how Laravel originally called the migration based on model Distribuidor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign Id in a migration with a table name that isn't the plural of the local key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71174180/foreign-id-in-a-migration-with-a-table-name-that-isnt-the-plural-of-the-local-k)

Comment: Also ensure you've set the pluralizer language correctly. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#pluralization-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Configuration: Ensure that your Distribuidor model specifies the custom table name correctly:

```
protected $table = 'distribuidores';
```

Migration Configuration: In your pivot table migration, explicitly specify the custom table names for foreign key constraints:

```
$table->foreignId('distribuidor_id')->constrained('distribuidores')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreignId('producto_id')->constrained('productos')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Foreign Key Types: Ensure that the types of foreign keys match the types of the referenced primary keys.

Migration Order: Ensure that migrations for distribuidores and productos tables run before the pivot table migration.

After making these adjustments, run php artisan migrate:fresh to reset migrations and try again. This should resolve the issue.